# PHPUNIT Zend framework how mock Zend_Registry::set to be tested against 1st datasource item only and unset it for the 2nd?

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I'm having an issue with creating this UT with PHPUNIT and Zend framework

**this is the function which the UT is made for:**

```
 protected function _functionToTest( $view ) 
 {
    if($this->domagick) {
        $view->details = array(
                   'important value' => Zend_Registry::get('importantvalue')
                   'Some String' => $this->_getZendHelper()
        );
    }
 }
```

**Note** that `$this->_getZendHelper()` is the function that brings in the `Zend_Registry::set('importantValue', '123');`

It fails the second assertion, should I create 2 separate tests?

Is there any way to make

```
Zend_Registry::set('importantValue', '123');
```

to run against the first data provider (data1)
and then on the *second* run, disable it? as it should be null, and it is creating an array instead of null.

Or should I mock it a particular manner?

my test code:

```
   /** @dataProvider functionToTestDataProvider
   */

    public function testfunctionToTest($message, $siteMagicSettings, $expected)
    {

        // this is the value that is I can't understand how to "reset"
        // for the second dataprovider test which expects null

        Zend_Registry::set('importantValue', '123');

        $myMockForDebug = $this->getMockBuilder('CLASS_Name_Jack')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(array('_getZendHelper, _functionToTest'))
            ->getMock();

        $myMockForDebug = $this->getPublicClass($myMockForDebug);
        $myMockForDebug->_siteMagicSettings = $siteMagicSettings;

        $myMockForDebug->expects($this->any())
            ->method('_getZendHelper')
            ->will($this->returnValue('hello world'));

        $zendFrameworkControllerFrontEndMockVariable= $this->getMockBuilder('Zend_Controller_Front')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(
                array(
                    'getMagicalContext';
                )
            )
            ->getMock();

        $myMockForDebug->_zendControllerFront = $zendFrameworkControllerFrontEndMock;
        $view = $myMockForDebug->_zendControllerFront;

        $myMockForDebug->_functionToTest($view);

        $this->assertEquals($expected , $view->details);
        $this->assertNull($expected , $view->details);


    }
```

my data provider:

```
    public function functionToTestDataProvider()
    {
        return [
            'data1'=> [
                    'message' => 'Do magick is true so it should create expected',
                    'siteMagicSettings' => (object) array(
                        'values' => (object) array(
                            'doMagick'=> 'true'
                        )
                    ),
                    'expected' => array(
                            'important value' => '123',
                            'Some String' => 'hello world'
                    ),
            ],
            'data2'=> [
                    'message' => 'Do magick is turned off',
                    'siteMagicSettings' => (object) array(
                        'values' => (object) array(
                            'doMagick'=> 'false'
                        )
                    ),
                    'expected' => null
            ]
        ];
    }
```

currently when I run the test , I get 1 Failure:

```
"data2" ('Do magick is turned off', stdClass, NULL)      
Array (...) does not match expected type "NULL".
```

Comment: Have you considered to pass the value from Zend_Registry as a function dependency? This change will allow you to forget about Zend_Registry and use any dataset you wish in your test and make the code more understandable.

Comment: @SergioRinaudo  please can you show me how would you do that in an answer? that would be great...or a link to have a reference.

Comment: Actually, I don't kown the code of "_functionToTest" but the main concept is to add the "importantValue" as an argument. And I would also remove the Zend_View instance from the argument and return just an array that will be later assigned to the $view. In practice the advice is to make a decoupling of the "_functionToTest" from Zend_Registry but also from Zend_View. If you can, publish the "_functionToTest" actual code.

Comment: @SergioRinaudo the function to test is right there, it says "this is the function tested". I really appreciate your help I'm learning a lot with this.

Comment: Updated the code to be more self explanatory, was missing the fact that  $this->_getZendHelper() is part of the function to be tested and is what brings in the value of Zend_Registry::set('importantValue', '123');

Comment: I thought it was just an example.. So where is the Zend_Registry's 'importantValue' used? In the view script? 
The main issue here is that you are actually trying to test Zend_View and not your function that is very simple.

Comment: yes, you are right, but it doesn't pass if I don't define this value inside the test. maybe is could only make it run against data1 and clear it when it runs against data2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all the comments I'll try to make an answer for this.
The main issue from my point of view is that your method to test is too much coupled with Zend components, that do not need to be tested, **they are already tested by the framework**.

So this is how I would refactor your code

```
protected function _functionToTest($carData, $helperString) {
    return [
        'important value' => $carData
        'Some String' => $helperString
    ];
}

// ..and somewhere
$helperString = $this->_getZendHelper();
$view->details = $this->domagick ? $this->_functionToTest($this->car, $helperString) : [];
```

Your function does actually make nothing more than creating an array.